# How to limit the result of select tag in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

For example, I have this:

```
result = soup.select('div#test > div.filters > span.text')
```

I want to limit the result of the above list to 10 items.

In case of `find_all()` one can use the `limit` argument but what about `select()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `limit` argument for `select()`, but you can *slice* the resultset:

```
soup.select('div#test > div.filters > span.text')[:10]
```

Comment: Ah, ok.
Can you tell me how to get the text inside the span element?
I know I can do result[0].text but I want it to return the text directly.

Comment: @RaghavSharma the usual approach is to use the `.text` property as you've shown. Also, if you need a text for every element matching the selector, you can use a list comprehension: `[item.text for item in result]`.

Answer (score 1):

There absolutely now is a `limit` argument.

[limit argument:](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

> This works just like the LIMIT keyword in SQL. It tells Beautiful Soup
> to stop gathering results after it’s found a certain number.

Applies to `find_all` and `select` methods.

E.g.,

```
result = soup.select('div#test > div.filters > span.text', limit = 10)
```